# EVM: ускорение вычисления

Tags: c++, видео, opencv

Для повторения эффекта [Eulerian Video Magnification](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/#publications) можно воспользоваться более простой техникой, нежели чем об этом говорится в соответствующей документации. Достаточно просто взять полосный фильтр, например, Баттерворта и подобрать к конкретному видео нижнюю и верхнюю частоты среза. Остаётся только применять этот фильтр к каждому из пикселей каждого кадра в кольцевом буфере. Всё это без необходимости разложения кадров на пирамиду изображений, а затем, перед воспроизведением, производить обратную сборку в одно целое.

Но мой вопрос заключается в том, каким образом авторы EVM достигают такой скорости обработки данных, как это представлено на их [демонстрационном видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONZcjs1Pjmk)?

Там показан ролик с вагоном метро достаточно высокого разрешения, пользователь крутит ползунки параметров, и всё в режиме реального времени, как если бы применялись простейшие расчёты. Ведь как минимум необходимо собрать кольцевой буфер размером, скажем, кадров в 30, и по каждому пикселю центрального в этом буфере кадра и основываясь на значениях пикселей других кадров в кольце, применять на них в отдельности полосный фильтр. Это огромная работа с учётом того, что изображение ещё и в цвете, то есть три канала.

Вопрос - как так у них это получается? Просто хотя бы чисто теоретически.

**Update:**

Максимум, что удалось добиться для воспроизведения в реальном времени - это разрешение в 320х240 пикселей, без применения пирамид Гаусса, а затем Лапласа (только один единственный проход на 3-х каналах по всем пикселям с применением полосного фильтра), на восьмиядерной машине, с параллелизацией через OpenMP, 25 кадров/сек.

Пересмотрел все проекты на гитхабе и прочих местах, какие только сумел найти по этой теме. Везде производится буферизация кадров и лишь затем постобработка.

Делаю вывод, что возможная неоптимизированность моего кода не является причиной невозможности наложения EVM в реальном времени. Значит авторы метода используют или некий хитрый подход, позволяющий избавиться от части вычислений, либо задействуют целый кластер машин. Впрочем, может быть ещё использование GPU... Одно из двух: либо вычисляют иначе, чем описывают в своей документации, либо используют "железо" по полной программе.

Comment: Я хочу предупредить, что обилие фамилий математиков в посте выше вызвало у меня священный трепет(другими словами, я не понимаю алгоритмов применённых на видео и описанных Вами), НО. Если там вся суть в том, чтобы обработать кучу пикселей быстро, но однотипно, то, фактически, не важно какая там сложная математика. Мы просто пишем шейдер и натравливаем его на каждый кадр. Это будет работать довольно шустро на любом современном железе. Хотя, повторюсь, чтобы дать какой-то дельный совет нужно понимать о чём речь, а я не понимаю.

Comment: Мы так делали для цветовой коррекции видео в реальном времени с использование LUT3D - всё работало шустро.

Comment: Никакого священного трепета вызываться не должно (надеюсь, что это не сарказм), т.к. это просто пояснение выражения "пирамида изображений", озвученного в вопросе ранее. В OpenCV для этих операций предусмотрено две функции pyrDown() и pyrUp() соответственно. Тем самым я подчеркнул, что ничего такого особенного, что может быть недоступно в простой реализации, EVM не декларирует. Другое дело - Ваши слова про шейдеры. То есть всё-таки GPU. Жаль лично для меня, так как я в этом направлении мало что понимаю. Я надеялся, что, возможно, просто с CPU эта проблема решаема.

Comment: не сарказм, я просто реально не понимаю(никогда не вникал) той математики, что используется в задаче выше. Т.е .математическую подоплёку задачи я оценить вообще не могу. Но сейчас любая задача, где надо большим массивом разных данных нужно выполнить однотипные операции должна быть перенесена на GPU. Не нужно его боятся, там всё реально просто. По крайней мере для таких простых вещей, как шейдер на видео кадр.

Comment: CPU просто не предназначен для таких задач, это вотчина GPU

Comment: Понял Вас. Оформите как ответ? На мой взгляд, теоретический ответ получен, а практический - вопрос сам по себе не подразумевает. Буду по возможности разбираться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные задачи лучше решать с использование GPU, т.к. CPU не заточен под SIMD задачи. Могу предложить примерный алгоритм решения с использование Qt/QML:

1. На форме размещаем `Image`, в который мы будем отрисовывать наш кадр.
2. На имеющийся `Image` натравливаем `ShaderEffect` с шейдером прописанным в `fragmentShader`.

Вуаля!

Шейдер будет состоять из той математики, которую нужно применить к каждому пикселю. Чтобы написать такой шейдер нужно просто посмотреть пару примеров, можно даже в документации Qt. Для таких базовых вещей и при известной математике, в этом нет ничего сложного.